# Call a function/Api at the time of program uninstallation

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, winapi

How the below scenario can be achieved,

1) There should be only one exe which should execute some code

2) Also, it should add an entry in the add/remove programs

3) When i uninstall the entry from add/remove programs, i need to call some functions/api's to complete the uninstallation.

Answer (score 2):

If the "call some functions/api's" you need is as simple as removing files at next reboot - make it a "delete on reboot" as explained [here](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/windows-nt-2000-xp/threads/6577/delete-files-on-restart):

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Delete on reboot\command]
>   @="CMD /E:OFF /C REG ADD >HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce /v \"Del %1 >OnNextReboot\" /d ^\"cmd.exe /c DEL /F /Q \\"%1\\"\" /f\""
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Open]
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Delete on reboot\command]
>   @="CMD /E:OFF /C REG ADD >HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce /v \"Del %1 >OnNextReboot\" /d ^\"cmd.exe /c RD /S /Q \\"%1\\"\" /f\""

To remove registry entries on reboot use this (explained [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic13777.html)):

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Delete on reboot\command]
>   @="CMD /E:OFF /C REG ADD >HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce /v \"Del %1 >OnNextReboot\" /d ^\"cmd.exe /c DEL /F /Q \\"%1\\"\" /f\""
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Open]
>   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\Delete on reboot\command]
>   @="CMD /E:OFF /C REG ADD >HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\RunOnce /v \"Del %1 >OnNextReboot\" /d ^\"cmd.exe /c RD /S /Q \\"%1\\"\" /f\""

Comment: I dont want to remove the files on reboot, I want to call some function call or Api. (For example, need to delete a certficate from the certificcate store, or call an exe )

Comment: Those can be done by your very program, no? Either write a separate binary to run at "uninstall-time" or have your main binary employ a special mode for uninstallation (using a command-line switch would probably be the easiest). That way what you do during uninstall is you call your necessary clean-up subroutines and then proceed with the regular uninstall process.

Comment: ya I can do it with my program. My question here is how to call that binary automatically while I'm uninstalling my package in control panel?